# Cant set cookies to secure flag in apache mod headers

Tags: apache, cookies, setcookie, cookie-httponly, mod-headers

I have added  below fix in my apache  vhost file

Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"

Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"

but in response header Im having this not secure flag not sure why < set-cookie: affinity="07*****17055b60"; Path=/; HttpOnly

Im not able to set secure flag to the cookie

I have added  below fix in my apache  vhost file

Header always edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; HTTPOnly; Secure"
Header onsuccess edit Set-Cookie (.*) "$1; SameSite=Strict; Secure"